# Will D2L support webhooks?

Tags: desire2learn

This is not a question per se, but it would be great if Desire2Learn supported [webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook).

Github does this - https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

If D2L were to support webhooks, this would greatly aid in development especially for applications that require synchronization.

For example, let's say I needed to synchronize a course's discussions.  With webhooks, after every discussion post, a POST request would be made to a specified URL and I would receive the data needed to synchronize it.

Without webhooks, I would need to do some form of cronjob and write some elaborate code to prevent duplicate activities, etc.

If a D2L representative is reading, please pass this on to the development team.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We do read questions tagged with `desire2learn`, but, as you point out, this isn't really a question. 8)

Webhooks are an extensibility technology that is under consideration by our development planning group, but we have no definite targeted release vehicle for such a feature at this time. Generally, the most important priority driver behind our feature roadmaps is our clients' expressed needs, so thanks very much for expressing your need to us.

We're also working on a set of expanded venues for interaction with our developer community so you don't need to ask these kind of "questions" here in the future. 8)